# Reference the url address to learn data mining algorithm C5.0

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Does anyone know about how to calculate the C5.0 data mining algorithm, it may be an address reference url?

Answer (score 2):

No, full version of the algorithm is commercial secret of [Rule Quest](http://rulequest.com/)

C5.0 is commercial improved version of C4.5. Some of these improvements are published, some of them are not published. You can read about this in [weka book](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/book.html). J4.8 is named so since it is java-based and its power is between C4.5 and C5.0.

You can see comparison of C4.5 and C5.0 [here](http://rulequest.com/see5-comparison.html.), and C4.5, J4.8 and C5.0 [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.158.4350&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

I found that [single threaded version is available](http://www.rulequest.com/see5-info.html) in GPL.